# Android studio not building project

Tags: android, xml, styles

Android resource linking failed
Output:  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:590: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:591: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:592: error: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar) not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:603: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:604: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:605: error: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar) not found.
error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:621: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:622: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:623: error: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:624: error: style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle (aka com.weiuit.LumnKey:attr/windowNoTitle)' not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Dell.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a5773728be23c4c145526f1a4035dad1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.weiuit.LumnKey\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        xxxhdpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\usman repository\office\lumnkey\LumnKeyStudio\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

**I tried every thing .invalidate cashe / restart ,cleaning ,downgrading dependencies,I am facing this in many old projects .**

Answer (score 0):

i think you have not created "style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" style in your style.xml and you are using that style in your manifest.make one style in manifest by this name or use any default NoActionBar style

have a look my app style

```
<style name="AppThemeWhite" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/app_them_colore</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering  but i have  style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" in xml